# cannot unhide/hide table row based on a checkbox.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form working where changing the value of a dropdown will hide or display a row.  What I can't get working is trying to hide or unhide a row based on a checkbox.

My Javascript_tag is

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
        $(document).ready(function(){
  //     if($("#observation_discussed_with_employee").is('checked'){
              $(".hidden_option_date_discussed").fadeIn('slow');
              alert("test");
    //     }
         });
 <% end %>
```

The style_add.css is

```
.hidden_option{
    display: none;
}

.hidden_option_date_discussed{
    display: none;
}
```

I have that stylesheet linked with `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style_adds" %>` (the other hide/show works so I know I am able to use this stylesheet

The checkbox field and the subsequent field I want to hide/unhide is below

```
    <tr>
              <div id="discussed">
                <td><%= f.label :discussed_with_employee %></td>
                <td><%= f.check_box :discussed_with_employee  %></td>
              </div>
        </tr>

        <tr class="hidden_option_date_discussed">
```

If I run the page with the if statements remarked out as shown, I get the alert box. However, if I unremark the if statements, then I don't see an alert.

```
        <div class="field" >
          <td><%= f.label :date_discussed %></td>
          <td><%= f.date_select( :date_discussed,  :default => 0.days.from_now, min: 1.year.ago) %></td>
        </div>
</tr>
```

Comment: just a note : if you have many TR you should change id="discussed"  to class="discussed"

Comment: The problem seems to be that I can't bind the js to the checkbox. I am using a browser tool that overlays the screen to show which elements have js bound to them. The performance field which is a dropdown works and is shown to have js bound to it. however, the checkbox won't do it. As a test I tried using a status dropdown and that worked. I suspect that the problem is either (1) rails has difficulty binding to a checkbox or (2) rails/js doesn't like the name of the field.. ie. discussed_with_employee vs status.  Perhaps the underscores in the name are causing an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the fact you're using a if statement. The way the if-statement works is it fires once, and that's it. The function you're looking for is `change()`. So it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#observation_discussed_with_employee").change(function(){
        if($("#observation_discussed_with_employee").is('checked'){
            $(".hidden_option_date_discussed").fadeIn('slow');
            alert("test");
        }
    });
});
```

It fires the if-statement each time the value of `#observation_discussed_with_employee` changes (so when it's either checked, or unchecked).

**Edit: As someone in the comments said, you still need to make an else-statement with fadeOut, so it works both ways.**

Comment: You may need to remake also de "fade" for else condition, otherway it will reamin as shown if unchecks the checkbox.

Comment: @DaniP Yes, but OP will probably be abled to do that himself, since he got quite far.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was caused by not being able to bind to a checkbox. I did things a little differenly and changed the checkbox to a 'yes/no' with values set to true  and false.

I added the following to the javascript

```
 if($("#observation_testchk").val() == "true"){
         $(".hidden_option_date_discussed").fadeIn('slow');
          }


   $("#observation_testchk").change(function(){
             if($("#observation_testchk").val() == "true"){
            //if($("#observation_testchk").val() == 1){
               $(".hidden_option_date_discussed").fadeIn('slow');
               }
            else if ($("#observation_testchk").val() == "false"){
                $(".hidden_option_date_discussed").fadeOut('slow');
                }
           });
```

and added this field

```
          <div class="field">
            <td><%= f.label :testchk %></td>
             <td><%= f.select :testchk, [['Yes','true'],['No','false']] %></td>
          </div>
```

That gives me a yes/no dropdown. Selecting yes or no will show/hide the other field appropriately. I still need to clean the code up a little but the main lesson was :

I could not get JS to bind to a checkbox. However, it would bind to a dropdown.

Comment: One other thing. I checked to see if having multiple underscores in the field name caused a failure.. ie. discussed vs discussed_with_employee. As far as I can tell, there is no effect.